# Images not visible when the same dashboard is viewed in different systems in Tableau

Tags: image, tableau-api

Images not visible when the same Tableau dashboard is viewed in different systems. Instead of the image, Cross marks are coming. The images are created as different sheets and have actions applied on them. Can anyone please inform how can we fix it?

Basically,

I want to create a link on the dashboard clicking which I will be directed to Another Sheet/Dashboard. So, I put an image and added Action to it, clicking this image you will be directed from the present dashboard to the other Dashboard. But the problem is the Image is visible in my workbook but when I'm sending this file to some other people, some of them are observing a "Cross" mark instead of the Image, but the action is working fine. I tried both tableau 8.0 & 8.1.It's persisting in both

Comment: Hello. Can you be more specific? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: I want to create a link on the dashboard clicking which I will be directed to Another Sheet/Dashboard. So, I put an image and added Action to it, clicking this image you will be directed from the present dashboard to the other Dashboard. But the problem is the Image is visible in my workbook but when I'm sending this file to some other people, some of them are observing a "Cross" mark instead of the Image, but the action is working fine. I tried both tableau 8.0 & 8.1.It's persisting in both

Comment: OK, please update your question with that information. Also, I am guessing that you are sharing a packaged workbook and you are sharing it with people that are also using tableau. I am guessing the image is an embedded image. If so, is it a link to a file on the internet or is it a file you are packaging with the workbook?

Comment: Yeah, I'm sharing the packaged workbook with people who are also using tableau. The image I have inserted from the 'Customs' option under 'shapes' selection. The link is to another dashboard in the same packaged workbook, not a file on the internet. Basically, from the "Sales Dashboard", I have given the link to view the "Appendix Dashboard" containing all the definitions of the metrics used in the Sales Dashboard. Hope, It's clear now.

Comment: Yes, and it is only the image that is not showing for some people, everything else works, right?

Comment: Yeah....Can you please tell why? Really need to fix it asap!

Comment: Is this workbook being saved as a workbook (.twb) or a packaged workbook (.twbx)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using tableau public keep this in mind:

> Tableau Public won't let you add an image file from the web. URLs can
>   be used to create links within a dashboard, but they cannot be used as
>   a file source. For an image, you would need to link to a physical file
>   location, not a URL. ([See post](http://www.tableausoftware.com/public/blog/2012/01/picture-perfect-adding-images-your-viz-part-1-1412))

If you are using tableau desktop and custom shapes, the problem might be that the other people viewing the dashboard do not have access to the file that contains the shape. I am guessing that you might need to share those files with them or go back to using a built in shape.

See more here: http://onlinehelp.tableausoftware.com/v6.1/public/online/en-us/i1114815.html

> To create custom shapes:
>
> 1. Create your shape image files. Each shape should be saved as its own
>      file and can be in many image formats including bitmap (.bmp),
>      portable network graphic (.png), JPEG, graphics interchange format
>      (.gif), and so on.
> 2. Place the shapes into the My Tableau Repository folder located in your
>      Documents folder. The shapes should be put into a new folder inside
>      the Shapes folder. The name of the folder will be used as the name of
>      the palette in Tableau.